# Libraries, CSS, and conditional loading

Tags: theming

In looking at the attached screen shot from mytheme.libraries.yml, I see 'base:', 'component', 'layout', 'theme', and so on.

Do these designations represent/do anything in practice? Or is this just for organization of the libraries.yml file, or does this imply where/when these CSS files load? For example, form.css only loads when a form is present.

I can see this happening in modules, but in the theme.libraries file?

Also, why isn't a 'yml' or 'yaml' tag available here? y

[image: Screen capture of a libraries file of a theme.]

Comment: Please don't add screenshots of code. Please paste the code and use the code highlighting functionality. Thank you 

Comment: I don't totally understand the question, what is a libraries.twig file? Libraries are declared in a libraries.yml file in a module or a theme.

Comment: Sorry - I'll post the code from now on and I'll also make sure I get my file extensions straight. Oops. thanks for the heads-up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should review the Adding stylesheets (CSS) and Javascript (JS) to a [Drupal module](https://www.drupal.org/node/2274843) and [Drupal theme](https://www.drupal.org/node/2216195) docs. Unfortunately, there's information in one that's not in the other, but *I believe* all of the information pertaining to defining a library, i.e. creating a libraries.yml file, applies to both modules and themes.

> Looking at mytheme.libraries.yml, I see 'base', 'component', 'layout',
> 'theme', and so on. **Do these designations represent/do anything in
> practice?**

Yes, they do stuff. Primarily, they change the order that the files are loaded (lower weights are loaded first). It's also a good way to organize your CSS (these keys only apply to CSS, not JS) conceptually so as to make it easier to find, debug, and fix any issues or make changes.

From the docs:

> [base, layout, component, state, theme keys] indicate the style type the CSS file belongs to.
>
> You can set CSS weights with 5 different levels of styling:
>
> - base: CSS reset/normalize plus HTML element styling. Key assigns a weight of `CSS_BASE = -200`
> - layout: macro arrangement of a web page, including any grid systems. Key assigns a weight of `CSS_LAYOUT = -100`
> - component: discrete, reusable UI elements. Key assigns a weight of `CSS_COMPONENT = 0`
> - state: styles that deal with client-side changes to components. Key assigns a weight of `CSS_STATE = 100`
> - theme: purely visual styling (“look-and-feel”) for a component. Key assigns a weight of `CSS_THEME = 200`
>
> This is defined by the [SMACSS](http://smacss.com/) standard. So here if you specify theme
> it means that the CSS file contains theme related styling which is
> pure look and feel. [More info here](https://www.drupal.org/node/1887922). You cannot use other keys as these
> will cause strict warnings.

These keys do not provide any conditional loading of the files. They're all always loaded when the library is included, the keys only change the order in which the individual files are loaded. (If you're using aggregation, they will all be in the one file, but the order will be preserved.) To conditionally load files, you'll need to create separate libraries (you can define multiple libraries in the same libraries.yml file) and then attach the individual libraries only when you need them.

There are a number of ways to attach a library to a page, see the [Attaching a Library to Page(s)](https://www.drupal.org/node/2274843#attaching) section of the module and theme docs noted above.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I wish I could find some templating tutorials that go beyond 'first, install barrio...' I'd like to get into preprocess and conditionals. Do more with templates and less with modules.

Answer (score 2):

`base`, `components` etc. are [SMACSS](http://smacss.com/book/categorizing) inspired categories, a method of organizing CSS in large scale projects (in Drupal this also means load order). And YAML in here makes no sense, you can't add YAML to a HTML document.